# Is this the bike shed phenomenon or is there a joke here that I'm missing?

Tags: discussion, gaming-the-system, bias

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610916/easiest-way-to-flip-a-boolean-value/610919#610919) asks, *how do you flip a boolean in C++*?
The answer, of course, is to use the single-character built-in operator made for doing exactly that.

Now, that's a perfectly good answer to a neophyte's question, but I'm willing to bet that at least 99.44% of C/C++ programmers are familiar with the `!` operator, so why did this answer receive 78 upvotes and a bounty of +500?

Seriously, I'm not here to complain about [the bike shed problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31253/the-bike-shed-problem-and-so). I'm really curious whether I'm missing some kind of "inside" joke. Enlighten me, please!

Comment: see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10682/are-reputation-lotteries-good-or-bad

Comment: There was some crazy voting going on in the first year of SO, no doubt.  This one however looks like an experiment with the new bounty system, introduced just a month earlier.  It worked, well over 4000 views for a ho-hum question.  From users who weren't shy about voting back then.

Answer (score 5):

What bounty, **I see no bounty**, just a user that was experimenting with sock puppets early in his career.

This is the bike shed effect, in action, mixed in with some deliberate gaming.

Comment: There is still +500 besides the answer, for 99.999% of the users it means "this answer won a bounty", even if there's really no bounty behind the scenes. :/